# Add records inline by using the last row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Is there a way to add records inline, like Postman does when adding params? This gif explains the desired result:
[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? Have you tried making use of the `tabToNextCell` (see [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#tabtonextcell) callback?

Comment: I've tried to find an example on how to achieve this, but haven't found any. I could try something with custom cell editors, but it seems to me that that isn't really efficient. So my question was more in the lines of is it possible to achieve this in an efficient way? Since AG-Grid doesn't really have a forum where these questions can be asked, I thought of asking it here, since that's what they advise you to.